# How to express the concept of "the degree of excitement" in one word?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there one word that encapsulates the degree to which something is exciting, for example on a spectrum of:

Calm |------------|------------| Thrilling

I've come up with a few possible words, but none of them seem to quite fit, for instance: 
"temperament", "emotion", "feeling".

Comment: [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/temperature) adds a broadened definition of 'temperature': _ relative state of emotional warmth_, but there are various different emotions, and calm ... ... ... seething is the usual continuum involved.

Comment: What is the context for requiring a single word? (Are you trying to find something that fits into a list of other single words thematically?)

Comment: @JasonBassford The context is a quantification of this feeling as it relates to a certain activity. I have a bunch of other words that measure other dimensions as well, for example 'physicality' which measures how physically difficult the activity is. The word would ideally reflect how 'rousing' a given activity is.

Comment: In that case, at least as single words in a list, *excitement* is of the same type of grammatical form as *physicality*. You can add *degree of* in front of both—or neither. If you use them in the context of a sentence, however, things could become different: *What is your physicality?* sounds mostly okay, but *What is your excitement?* does not. But that depends on the sentence.

Comment: I agree with you that ‘excitement’ technically fits the bill (as in *the level of excitement*), but to me it seems that it invokes more of the feelings of ‘rousing’, ‘thrilling’, ‘invigorating’ as opposed to the ‘calm’ end of the spectrum. Does a word exist that is more neutral?
 
As an analogy, I could also label ‘physicality’ as ‘strain’. You can have ‘zero’ level physical strain on the left side or ‘ten’ level strain on the right, but the word itself leans towards the right end of the spectrum.

Comment: *Excitedness* doesn't quite work based on dictionary definitions, e.g., M-W, but to my ear it opens up the possibility of different levels of excitement compared to *excitement* by itself.

Comment: When you say *physicality* or *strain* and you have a zero to ten scale, do you also have words on that scale, like you have suggested that you do on the "temperament" scale? Or is the "temperament" scale also zero to ten?

Comment: @TinfoilHat Yes I have labels on the 'physicality' scale also: it goes from 'mild' to 'strenuous'. All dimensions are quantified from 0 to 10 and are accompanied by labels.

Comment: The problem is that *mild --> strenuous* actually seem like scale words -- like zero to ten --  whereas *calm --> thrilling* do not. To be parallel, I think you need (roughly) something like a scale called "engagement" and then scale words like *a little* and *a lot*.

Comment: energizing - give vitality and enthusiasm to; stimulation level; invigoration level

Comment: invigoration - the activity of giving vitality and vigour to something. vivification, animation. activating, energizing, activation - the activity of causing to have energy and be active. The Free Dictionary

Comment: @TinfoilHat hmmm, that's a good point.

Comment: if *mild physicality --> strenuous physicality* then perhaps *minimal invigoration --> maximum invigoration*

Answer (score 1):

*Degree of excitement* is the most precise way to put it. However, in psychology research [[1]](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=q8tUSCDORzwC&oi=fnd&pg=PR1&dq=psychology%20encyclopedia&ots=B-X7Nax0pb&sig=PxlDzriT1PMz3n9zH6jUefGv-wM#v=onepage&q=excitement&f=false), when measuring excitement quantitatively on a scale, the terms *excitement* and *arousal* can be used to label that type of measurement.

If that does not fit your purpose, and you still need a "single-word" label (perhaps for word count purposes), you could use *excitement-level*, but this is a bit sneaky.

Source: [Spielberger, C. (2004). *Encyclopedia of applied psychology*. Academic press.](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=q8tUSCDORzwC&oi=fnd&pg=PR1&dq=psychology%20encyclopedia&ots=B-X7Nax0pb&sig=PxlDzriT1PMz3n9zH6jUefGv-wM#v=onepage&q=excitement&f=false)